# TypeError: can't access property "appendChild", elemento_existente is null

Tags: javascript

Tengo este código el cual, yo creo, no tiene nada de complicado. Es sólo anexar.

```js
var contenido = document.createTextNode('Hola, amigo');
    var elemento_existente = document.getElementById('parrafo');
    
    function cargar(){
            elemento_existente.appendChild(contenido);
    }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <htmln lang="es">
    <head>
    <title>Problema</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="funciones.js"></script>
    <link rel="StyleSheet" href="estilos.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <p id="parrafo">
    
    </p>
    
    <button onclick="cargar()">Rellenar</button>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Pero la consola me manda este error

```
TypeError: can't access property "appendChild", elemento_existente is null
```

Comment: ese codigo funciona

Comment: Esta línea: **<script src="funciones.js"></script>** la tienes antes de que el elemento exista en el DOM, entonces muévela antes de la etiqueta `</div>` de cierre

Comment: Ahora que la pregunta fue editada y el usuario puso el HTML, el problema es reproducible (pero no aqui en los snippet), para poder reproducir el problema debe ser probado en local.

Answer (score 1):

Tu codigo funciona de manera correcta, lo que pasa es que tu `script` esta siendo cargado **antes** de que la pagina se cargue (contenido del **body** para abajo), por este motivo los elementos aunque estén definidos no existen, hay dos formas de solucionarlo.

Aquí un ejemplo de que tu código si funciona:

```js
//Encerramos todo el codigo en window.onload para esperar a que cargue la pagina
window.onload = ()=>{

  var contenido = document.createTextNode('Hola, amigo');
  var elemento_existente = document.getElementById('parrafo');

  function cargar(){
     elemento_existente.appendChild(contenido);
  }

}
```

```html
<p id = "parrafo"></p>
```

Una cosa mas, al meter tu codigo dentro de `window.onload` puedes tener otro reference error marcando que la función `cargar` no existe, si deseas usar `window.onload` como solucion deberas de quitar el evento de tu boton:

```
<button>Rellenar</button>
```

y añadirselo desde `javascript` al boton:

```js
//Encerramos todo el codigo en window.onload para esperar a que cargue la pagina
window.onload = ()=>{

  var contenido = document.createTextNode('Hola, amigo');
  var elemento_existente = document.getElementById('parrafo');
  //Obtenemos el boton
  const boton = document.getElementById("botonRellenar");

  function cargar(){
     elemento_existente.appendChild(contenido);
  }
  
  //Añadimos el evento al boton:
  boton.addEventListener("click", cargar);

}
```

```html
<p id = "parrafo"></p>
<button id = "botonRellenar">Rellenar</button>
```

En caso de no querer usar window.onload otra opcion es mover tu `script` al final del `body`, es un truco usado por muchas personas, entonces tu script pasa de estar aqui:

```
<head>
    <title>Problema</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="funciones.js"></script>
    <link rel="StyleSheet" href="estilos.css" type="text/css">
</head>
```

A estar aqui:

```
<body>
...
...
...<script src="funciones.js"></script>
</body>
```

Y ya no deberias poner tu codigo dentro de `window.onload` y podrias usar directamente tu `button` como lo tenias:

```
<button onclick="cargar()">Rellenar</button>
```

Por cierto tu `'Hola, amigo'`, me recordo a la serie `Mr.Robot`, gran easter egg ;3.

Comment: aclaras que el tema es el orden?

Comment: Seguro, @gbianchi gracias por la sugerencia ya edito la respuesta.